# Flask | HTML not rendering data sent via render_template

Tags: html, flask, routes

I am making a query to my database, creating an object, and sending it to my HTML via `render_template`.

The issue I am having is that the HTML is not displaying the information.

Relevant code:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST','GET'])
def profile():
    if 'sno' in session:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            user = session['sno']
            print(user)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `sno` LIKE '{}'.format(user))
            r = cursor.fetchall()
            print(r)
            return render_template('profile.html', r=r)

    return redirect('/')
```

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="/edit" name="Name">                    
  <label>First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="{{r[1]}}" >
  <label>Last Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="{{r[2]}}" >
  <label>Age</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" value="{{r[3]}}">
  <label>CNIC</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnic" value="{{r[4]}}">
  <label>gender:</label>
    <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" value="{{r[5]}}"><br>
  <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uemail" value="{{r[6]}}">
  <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="upassword" class="form-control" value="{{r[7]}}"><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" name="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain your problem more elaborately?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this will work but try `r = curser.one()`

Answer (score 0):

I just did this

I had kept method = "POST".I changed it to  method="GET"
It worked like boom